# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '20' (T_LNUMBER) in on line 39

Tags: php, post, syntax-error

Hello Guys I have problem in this script
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '20' (T_LNUMBER) in on line 39

```
<?php  
  header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 
  echo '<p>Zamowienie przyjete o: <br/>'; 
  echo date('H:i.jSF'); 
  echo '</p>';  //Opis do daty //H - godzina w systemie 24 H // i - minuty // j - dzien miesiaca   //S - przedrostek porzadkowy TH //F - miesiac dodany slownie   
  echo'<p>Panstwa zamowienie wyglada nastepujaco: </p>'; 
  echo $_POST['iloscopon'].'&nbsp opon</br>'; 
  echo $_POST['iloscoleju'].'&nbsp oleju</br>'; 
  echo $_POST['iloscswiec'].'&nbsp swiec</br>'; 
  echo $_POST['ilosczarowek'].'&nbsp żarówki</br>'; 
  echo $_POST['ilosctlokow'].'&nbsp tłoki</br>';   // zliczanie ilosci zamowionych towarow   $ilosc=0;
  $ilosc=$_POST['iloscopon']+$_POST['iloscoleju']+$_POST['iloscswieac']+$_POST['ilosczarowek']+$_POST['ilosctlokow']; 
  echo 'Ilosc zamowionych towarow: '.$ilosc.'<br/>';   //zliczanie wartosci zamowionych towarow   $wartosc=0.00; 
  define('CENAOPON',100); 
  define('CENAOLEJU',50); 
  define('CENASWIEC',30); 
  define('CENAZAROWEK',15); 
  define('CENATLOKOW',50);

  //zliczenie ceny transportu if ($_POST['ile']=='a')  
  define('DOPIECIU,'20); elseif ($_POST['ile']=='b')  
  define('DODZIESIECIU',30); elseif ($_POST['ile']=='c')  
  define('DOPIETNASTU',35); elseif ($_POST['ile']=='d')  
  define('DODWUDZIESTUPIECIU',50);   
  $wartosc=$_POST['iloscopon']*CENAOPON+$_POST['iloscoleju']*CENAOLEJU+$_POST['iloscswiec']*CENASWIEC+$_POST['ilosczarowek']*CENAZAROWEK+$_POST['ilosctlokow']*CENATLOKOW+$_POST['a']*DOPIECIU+$_POST['b']*DODZIESIECIU+$_POST['c']*DOPIETNASTU+$_POST['d']*DODWUDZIESTUPIECIU; 
  echo 'Cena netto:&nbsp'.number_format($wartosc,2).'PLN<br/>';   
  $stawkavat=0.23; 
  $wartosc=$wartosc*(1+$stawkavat); 
  echo 'Cena brutto:&nbsp'.number_format($wartosc,2).'PLN<br/>';   //konstrukcja if 
  if($ilosc==0) 
    echo 'Na poprzedniej stronie nie zostalo zlozone zamowienie!<br/>';   //konstrukcja if z zastosowaniem bloku kodu 
  if($ilosc==0) {
        echo'<font color=red>'; echo 'Na poprzedniej stronie nie zostala podana ilosc produktow!'; 
  echo'</font>';
  } 
?>
```

Next Error: **Notice**:  Undefined Index: a in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moje\przetworz.php** on line **47**

**Notice**:  Undefined Index: b in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moje\przetworz.php** on line **47**

**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant DODZIESIECIU - assumed 'DODZIESIECIU' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moje\przetworz.php** on line **47**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: c in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moje\przetworz.php** on line **47**

**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant DOPIETNASTU - assumed 'DOPIETNASTU' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moje\przetworz.php** on line **47**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: d in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moje\przetworz.php** on line **47**

**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant DODWUDZIESTUPIECIU - assumed 'DODWUDZIESTUPIECIU' in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moje\przetworz.php** on line **47**
Cena netto:&nbsp1,700.00PLN
Cena brutto:&nbsp2,091.00PLN

The script is run on the principle when I choose the Form A to give me an adequate sum to the total bill

Thanks for Help ;)

Comment: for starters it would be good to format your code and not have it one line

Comment: what is line 20 atleast?

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error with this definition

```
define('DOPIECIU,'20);
```

It should be:

```
define('DOPIECIU',20);
```

Comment: Can you help me more ? :P

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error with

```
define('DOPIECIU,'20);
```

It must be

```
define('DOPIECIU',20); //placed ' after DOPIECIU from before 20
```